# Tornar um menu realmente responsivo

Tags: jquery

tenho um menu com varias divs nele com conteúdo, esse site que estou desenvolvendo o cliente terá acesso para editar e excluir elementos que quiser do site, então esses itens de dentro do menu precisao sempre estar no meio, porem não estou conseguindo fazer o jQuery gerenciar isso, por exemplo, se houver uma div apenas a classe css deve mudar, se for duas, deve ser outras propriedades, segue meu código atual:

```js
 var numCells = $("div.secondMenuButtonsCell").length;
  alert(numCells);
  if(numCells == 1){
$(".secondMenuButtonsCell").css({
  "width": "50% !important",         
  "margin-right": "auto !important",
  "margin-left": "auto !important"
  "border-right":"1px solid #CCCCCC !important",
  "height": "71px !important",
  "padding": "14px !important",
  "display": "inline-grid !important"
         });
              $("a.btnContentRow").css({
             "display": "inline-block !important",
              "text-align": "left !important"
                    }); };
```

porém esse código não esta alterando a classe, eu fiz algo errado?

Answer (score 1):

Não estou vendo código para alterar classe em seu script.

aconselho você criar uma classe no css para o estilo especificado como por exemplo:

```
 .meu-estilo1{
      width: 50% !important;         
      margin-right: auto !important;
      margin-left: auto !important;
      border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
      height: 71px !important;
      padding: 14px !important;
      display: inline-grid !important;
             }
```

para contar a div será necessário um seletor # ou . acompanhado de um nome para capturar no jquery.

exemplo no HTML:

```
 <div class="teste"></div>
```

no jQuery você faz a verificação da seguinte forma:

```
var $div = $('.teste');
var num_div = $div.size();

if (num_div == 1) {

   $div.removeClass('outras classes de estilo');
   $div.addClass('meu-estilo1');
}
```